# Specified cast is invalid - C#

Tags: c#

I have created a table in SQL server with column OrderId as BigInt datatype. When i compare two datatables in c# i got the following error.

> Specified cast is Invalid

Code is below.

```
  var idsNotInB = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<long>("OrderId"))
            .Except(dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<long>("OrderId")));


   DataTable TableC = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        join OrderId in idsNotInB
                        on row.Field<long>("OrderId") equals (long)OrderId
                        select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Please anyone guide how to deal with this error, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Please see image below. I have used bigint datatype and after it i write the above c# code.

[image]

Comment: Is the `OrderId` column in database nullable?

Comment: Debug and watch which datatype the DataTable is using. Field Method is very strict there.

Comment: What is the type of `OrderId` in `...equals (long)OrderId`?

Comment: Allow Nulls is false of that column in both tables(non nullables) . I also used (?) but same error. Any other idea please...

Comment: @RaufAbid Did you use bigint datatype for the "OrderId" field in both tables dt and dt1 in the database?

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy, Yes please see image in my original question in Edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the [`Field<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) method throws an [InvalidCastException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx) when trying to unbox the value from the underlying database table. Could you please check if all values in both tables dt and dt1 are convertable to long:

```
dt                  // check it also for dt1
  .AsEnumerable()
  .SelectMany(_ => _.ItemArray)
  .Select(_ => new { Value = _, Type = _.GetType() })
  .Where(_ => _.Type != typeof(long))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

A litte workaround by casting to `object` and then to `string` can help in this case:

```
var idsNotInB = dt
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(_ => _.Field<object>("OrderId").ToString())
                  .Except(dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(_ => _.Field<object>("OrderId").ToString()));

DataTable TableC = dt
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(_ => idsNotInB.Contains(_.Field<object>("OrderId").ToString()))
                     .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I check both dt but found nothing except long data type in both 'dt'. But fortunately your second method works nicely. I have little ques: will it comfortable with <object> type and work accurate and fast instead of using long datatype? Many thanks :)

Comment: @RaufAbid Certain speed overhead due to string conversion and string comparison could take place but the result should be accurate.

Comment: Thanks. Last question: how can i count:   var idsNotInB. Really thanks....

Comment: @RaufAbid one possible solution: `dt.AsEnumerable().Select(_ => _["OrderId"].ToString()).Except(dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(_ => _["OrderId"].ToString())).Count();`

Comment: Thanks @Andriy! helping me till end :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast to `long?` instead of `long`.
This might happen if the column is nullable in DB as MZetko failrly mentioned